# Delete one object from a JSON file using python

Tags: python, list, discord.py

```
@Bot.command()
async def cl(ctx,member:discord.Member = None):
    with open("C:\python3\economy.json","r") as f:
        json.load(f)
        queue.remove(str(member.id))
        with open("C:\python3\economy.json","w") as f:
            json.dump(f)
```

I need to delete only highlighted text оn the picture:
[json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RW0LT.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Have you looked up how to remove an entry out of a JSON file? There are many posts about it on StackOverflow. You may also take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 errors:

1. You haven't defined `queue`
2. There's no such method as `dict.remove`, you're looking for `dict.pop`
3. You're not saving anything into your JSON file

Fixing your code

```py
with open("C:\python3\economy.json", "r") as f:
    queue = json.load(f)  # defining `queue`

queue.pop(str(member.id))  # removing the key

with open("C:\python3\economy.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(queue, f)  # saving into the JSON file
```

Comment: Now I have that: Object of type TextIOWrapper is not JSON serializable

Comment: Thank you so much!